# How to remove enum variant tag from custom enum?

Tags: json, rust, enums, hashmap, serde

I define an `enum ZcMapValue` use as `V` for `HashMap<K,V>`, but when I serialize `ZcMapValue` to JSON , I got some problem, my code like the code bellow:

```rust
use serde::Serialize;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Serialize)]
pub enum ZcMapValue {
    LongValue(i128),
    FloatValue(f64),
    BoolValue(bool),
    StringValue(String),
    VecValue(Vec<ZcMapValue>),
    VecMapValue(Vec<HashMap<String, ZcMapValue>>),
    MapValue(HashMap<String, ZcMapValue>),
}

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert("A_B".to_string(), ZcMapValue::StringValue("a".to_string()));
    map.insert("B_C".to_string(), ZcMapValue::LongValue(128));
    let ser_js = serde_json::to_string_pretty(&map).unwrap();
    println!("{}", ser_js);
}
```

When I run the code I want:

```json
{"A_B": "a", "B_C": 128}
```

But the result is:

```json
{
  "B_C": {
    "longValue": 128
  },
  "A_B": {
    "stringValue": "a"
  }
}
```

How can I fixed it?

Comment: I hope it's alright that I simplified your code to better highlight the issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to get that format you can use [`#[serde(untagged)]`](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#untagged).

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Serialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum ZcMapValue {
    LongValue(i128),
    FloatValue(f64),
    BoolValue(bool),
    StringValue(String),
    VecValue(Vec<ZcMapValue>),
    VecMapValue(Vec<HashMap<String, ZcMapValue>>),
    MapValue(HashMap<String, ZcMapValue>),
}
```

Now your `println!` should correctly output:

```
{
  "A_B": "a",
  "B_C": 128 
}
```

If you don't want it pretty printed, then you simply have to use [`serde_json::to_string()`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.61/serde_json/fn.to_string.html) instead of [`serde_json::to_string_pretty()`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.61/serde_json/fn.to_string_pretty.html).